# where to put non-model classes in django

Tags: python, django

I'm now using django 1.6

As I know, if I want to use some model classes (using ORM) I should put them under folder `myapp/models.py`.

So what if I want to write some non-model classes (not using ORM), i.e. `class Util`, and only contains some globally used methods, maybe date formatting or something else.

So, where should these code locate? Is there a generally used way to this case?

Comment: wherever you want; it's your namespace.  (`Util` sounds like a very questionable name for a _class_ though)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can really put them anywhere you like, but I follow the pattern Django itself uses (in [admin](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin), [cache](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/core/cache), etc.) and put such things in a `utils.py` file. I have one (if necessary) in each app folder, as well as one for the whole project.